# How to flutter web with phone auth using firebase plugin please define complete step for flutter web

Tags: flutter

I am using firebase plugin to authentication with email and password in flutter web. I am done with this one.

Now I want to authenticate flutter web with phone_auth. I am using the same plugin and in this plugin, a future method which is called signInWithPhoneNumber(String phoneNumer, ApplicationVarifier verifier). I follow the rule on the firebase for application verifier. There, I learn about ReCaptchaVarifier which verifies the user with reCaptcha technique. But there is no way to integrate reCaptcha in flutter web.

If you solved my problem then it will be great opportunity for me to getting my job. Thanks I am waiting for your response

Answer (score 0):

Flutter for Web is currently in development, therefore firebase support isn't yet ready... It may come in the near future. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

As at now Flutter Web is not yet ready for Production and it does not support these yet.

You should consider using other dart frameworks.

And No, you can not write HTML code for flutter web.

Comment: And is there any way,As we make packages for flutter to comunicate with ios and android. Like this can we make recaptcha package for flutter web

Comment: I don't think thats possible yet. Maybe in the future.

Comment: Ok, Can we integrate javascript code in flutter web

Comment: All these are not available for now. As i said before, Flutter Web is still under development. Maybe this things will be available in future.

Comment: i created a flutter web project with fireabse. login, sign up, user session managing, and user profile data. Butt there is little bit problem only phone authentication

Comment: Did you get an error? if yes post the error, if no, describe your issue

Comment: the issue is that signInwithPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, ApplicationVerifier applicationVerifier) takes two required parameter one is the phone number and other is the reCaptcha verifiction. Phone number is ok butt reCaptcha does not know how get in flutter web